# Disable GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a simple memory game.
But i want to turn off the tap function.

When I use `imageViewGurka1.gestureRecognizers=NO;` it works, but I get the warning message: `Initialization of pointer of type 'NSArray *' to null from a constant boolean expression`. (what should I do to fix this warning message?)

And if I use this `imageViewGurka1 setUserInteractionEnable:NO;` I don't get a warning message, but I will not be able to move the image any more.

Here is some of the code.

```
-(IBAction)handleTapGurka1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

if (imageViewGurka1.tag == 0) {
    [imageViewGurka1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memorySångerGurka.png"]];
    imageViewGurka1.tag=1;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageViewGurka1];

}

else {
    [imageViewGurka1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"memorySångerBaksida.png"]];
    imageViewGurka1.tag=0;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageViewGurka1];
}

if (imageViewGurka1.tag==1 && imageViewGurka2.tag==1) {
    NSURL *musicFile;
    musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"applader"
                  ofType:@"mp3"]];
    myAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [myAudio play];
    //[imageViewGurka1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    //[imageViewGurka2 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    imageViewGurka1.gestureRecognizers=NO;
    imageViewGurka2.gestureRecognizers=NO;
}

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Regards

Comment: `gestureRecognizers` is not a boolean (as the error states), and no attempt has been made to consult the documentation on UIGestureRecognizer, where the answer is quite plain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`gestureRecognizers` is an array that contains all gesture recognizers attached to the view. You should loop through all gesture recognizers in that array and set their `enabled` property to false like this:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer * g in imageViewGurka1.gestureRecognizers) {
    g.enabled = NO;
}
```

**Swift 5**

Below the equivalent for Swift 5

```
for gesture in imageViewGurka1.gestureRecognizers! {
    gesture.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: if i put that code after [myAudio play]; i get the error message: Expected '(' after for' ... where should i put the "( )" Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, sorry for the mistake. I wrote the answer in Swift, not Obj-C. I've changed it to Obj-C now. Buy if you can't tell the difference, you should study the language first before trying to develop apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did do like this.
               for (UIGestureRecognizer *Gurka1 in imageViewGurka1.gestureRecognizers) {
            Gurka1.enabled = NO;
        }
        
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *Gurka2 in imageViewGurka2.gestureRecognizers) {
            Gurka2.enabled = NO;
        }

Comment: That's right. I forgot the * operator. That's what happens when you keep switching between two different languages :) Please accept the answer.

Comment: Accept the answer? Where do i do that?

Comment: There is a checkmark (tick) icon on the left side of this post, just click that and make it green :)

Answer (score 6):

At swift4,

Well in case of many gestures on many views you can enable and disable a gesture like this.

Lets say we have UIView array and we want to disable a gesture which is the first gesture added to the first view in view array named as ourView.

```
   ourView[0].gestureRecognizers![0].isEnabled = false
```

Also you can enable or disable all the gestures at the same time like this.

```
   for k in 0..<ourView.count {
      for l in 0..<outView[k].gestureRecognizers.count {
         ourView[k].gestureRecognizers![l].isEnabled = false 
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Storyboard/Outlet Solution**

*Background:*
I had a UIView that I wanted to act like a button so I added a tap gesture recognizer to it. When a user taps the 'button' I wanted to disable the button, perform some animation, and re-enable the button after the animation.

*Solution:* If you're using storyboards and you added a gesture recognizer to a UIView, control+drag from the gesture recognizer into the assistant editor to create an outlet. Then you can set `gestureRecognizerName.isEnabled = false`.

```
@IBOutlet var customButtonGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func didTapCustomButton(_ sender: Any) {
    customButtonGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
    performSomeAnimation(completionHandler: {
        self.customButtonGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
    })
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer), you could also use:

```
func removeTarget(Any?, action: Selector?)
```